# Type 'Promise<boolean | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean>'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

estaba practicando con Angular y quería hacer una autenticación "falsa" de usuario para restringir el acceso a ciertos componentes, pero me esta dando un error que no entiendo como solucionar. Tengo un service en el que establezco si ha iniciado sesión o no y devuelvo una promesa que simula que tarda unos 800ms:

```
loggedIn : boolean = false;

isAuthenticated(){
    const promise = new Promise( 
        (resolve, reject) =>{ 
            setTimeout(()=>{ 
                resolve(this.loggedIn);
            },800); 
        }
    );

    return promise;
}


login(){
    this.loggedIn = true;
}

logout(){
    this.loggedIn = false;
}
```

Y el servicio Guard inyecta el servicio previo que os he comentado y utilizo el método canActivate donde el código lo hago de esta forma:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean{
   return this.authService.isAuthenticated()
        .then(
            (authenticated : boolean) => { 
                if(authenticated){
                    return true; 
                }else{
                    this.router.navigate(['/']); 
                }
            }
        );
}
```

Pero me esta constantemente dando un error de que no lo puedo asignar:

> error TS2322: Type 'Promise<boolean | undefined>' is not assignable to
> type 'boolean | Observable | Promise'.   Type
> 'Promise<boolean | undefined>' is not assignable to type
> 'Promise'.
> Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Y error a la hora de recibir el argumento:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '(authenticated: boolean) => true |
> undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown) =>
> true | PromiseLike<true | undefined> | undefined'.   Types of
> parameters 'authenticated' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

El primer error me marca en el código:

```
   return this.authService.isAuthenticated()
        .then(

        );
```

y el segundo:

```
 (authenticated : boolean) =>
```

Aun poniendo en vez de boolean el any me indica otro error siguiente:

> error TS7030: Not all code paths return a value.
>
> ```
>             (authenticated : any) => {
> ```

Algo se me escapa y no se como arreglar este error

Comment: ¿Podrías por favor señalar las líneas en las que te da el error? Por otro lado, no puedes asignar nada a algo `unknown`, intenta `(value: any) `

Comment: He editado la pregunta, he probado con el any anteriormente y seguía el mismo fallo y tenia que igualmente cambiar todo lo boolean por any lo que no entiendo es porque si al final estoy devolviendo inicialmente un boolean.

Comment: Ya con `any` tiene más sentido. Si lo lees, de hecho, el error es claro _Not all code paths return a value_ Estás diciéndole a typescript que vas a retornar un boleano o bien `<Promise<boolean>` pero resulta que si `authenticated` es `false` no retornas nada y nunca declaraste que ibas a retornar algo `undefined` (o sea nada).

Comment: Pero en un principio la variable ya esta inicializada a false y a la hora de hacer la promesa devolverá este boolean que será false o true, pero nunca nada. Quizás no me he enterado muy bien a que te refieres

Comment: `canActivate` devuelve, según lo que tienes declarado, una de estas 3 cosas `Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean`. Ahora imagina que llamas a la función `this.authService.isAuthenticated()` responde `false` llama a la función del then, y se encuentra con está línea `this.router.navigate(['/']);` y termina la función sin un `return`. Dijiste que ibas a retornar algo pero no retornaste Nada!!!. Retornaste `Promise<undefined>` De ahí que te diga _no todos los caminos retornan un valor_ (Not all code paths return a value.)

Comment: Ponle después del `this.router.navigate(['/']);` un `return false;`

Comment: Oh vaya, no caí en eso, muchas gracias por la explicación me ha quedado claro y funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Tienen que devolver un valor todos los caminos es el error que te muestra y te comento Jaime Menendez .Con el codigo ordenado de esta forma me parece se ve claramente el porque del error

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GuardCanActiveGuard implements CanActivate {
  loggedIn : boolean = false;
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    
  }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> 
    | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree
     {
    return this.isAuthenticated()
  }
  isAuthenticated():Observable<boolean | UrlTree> 
  |Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return new Promise( 
        (resolve, reject) =>{ 
            setTimeout(()=>{ 
                resolve(this.loggedIn);
            },800); 
        }
    ).then(
      (authenticated :any) => { 
        if(authenticated){
            return true; 
        }else{
            this.router.navigate(['/']); 
            return false
        }
    }
    )

    
}


login(){
    this.loggedIn = true;
}

logout(){
    this.loggedIn = false;
}
}
```